# How possible get result from "<?for-each:" to line?

Tags: bi-publisher

How possible get result from "for-each"  to line/row and add symbol comma (on the rtf template for bi publisher).
As example my request:

```
<?for-each: BillingAccounts?>
<?if: EffectiveDate EffectiveDate!= ‘’?> 
<?EffectiveDate?>,
<?end if?>
<?end for-each?>
```

result-unsuccessful (we have date and comma but we see information in Column need row)

```
09/03/2020,
09/02/2020,
09/03/2020,
```

Or second option:

```
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'MN', EffectiveDate )?>
<?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'MN')?>
```

result-unsuccessful (we have date in row - its good , but without comma)

```
09/03/2020 09/02/2020 09/03/2020
```

expected result: 09/03/2020,09/02/2020,09/03/2020

Answer (score 2):

The if statement implicitly adds a newline.

Try `<?if@inlines:EffectiveDate EffectiveDate!= ‘’?`

Comment: There are also @ row, and @ column attributes. More here: https://cleartext.blogspot.com/2009/07/bip-if-then-else.html